# How can I give access to WordPress site using an Android application ?

Tags: android

I´m using an Android Application to obtain information after that I need to redirect this application to WordPress to show the information that this  obtained but I don't want that the user needs to retype his username and password  to access to WordPress because he wrote them in the moment that he login in the Android application. I don't know if this is possible, but I will be very grateful if you can tell me any suggestion.
Best regards.